Liouville's Theorem — proof of fundamental theorem of algebra
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
Why is it not sufficient to simply say the following:

If $\on{P}\left(z\right)$ is a polynomial with no roots, then $\left\vert\on{P}\left(Z\right)\right\vert$ is bounded below by $0$.
So $\left\vert 1/\on{P}\left(Z\right)\right\vert$ is bounded above by infinity.
I suppose this is not sufficient to say that $\left\vert 1/\on{P}\left(Z\right)\right\vert$ is bounded as it can still get arbitrarily close to infinity ?.
So we need some lower bound $R > 0$ ?.


If $P(z)$ is a complex polynomial, then I don't know even know what it means for it to be bounded below by $0$. There is no standard way to order the complex numbers. Do you mean $|P(z)|$?

Can you explain what's the difference you see between a function being bounded and a function being really bounded?

@Joe Yes—edited the post.

@JoséCarlosSantos I meant that saying |P(Z)| > 0 might seem sufficient to suggest |1/P(Z)| is bounded above but in actuality it is not sufficient.

I think you basically understand it. If $|P(z)|>0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$, then it can still be the case that $|P(z)|$ takes arbitrarily large values, i.e. for all $M>0$ there is a $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|P(z)|> M$. So the mere the fact that $|P|$ is strictly positive is not enough to conclude that $|1/P|$ is bounded above. So yes, this is why the number $R$ is needed in the proof.

What's the point of even talking about a real function being bounded above by infinity? Isn't every function from a set $S$ into $\Bbb R$ bounded above by infinity?

@Joe Ok that's what I figured. But then this prompts the follow up. In Stein, they show that for |z|>R we have some non-zero lower bound (az^n) and so |P(Z)| is bounded below outside the disc of radius R. That makes sense. But then they state that—"Since P is continuous and has no roots in the disc |z| ≤ R, it is bounded from below in that disc as well." Now if this simply means |P(Z)| > 0 in the disc then it fails to be a lower bound. So I presume the fact that P(Z) is continuous means that in the disc which is a compact set, it can't get arbitrarily close to 0 without actually equaling 0?

"bounded by infinity"?

@james: I don't have the book you are referring to on me, so I can't say for sure, but that seems about right. But you seem to be using language a little imprecisely: if $|P(z)|>0$ for all $z$ on that disc, then $|P(z)|$ is certainly bounded from below on that disc. But yes, we need more refined information to reach the conclusion that we want: if $0$ were the greatest lower bound of $|P|$ (restricted to the disc), then since a continuous real-valued function on a compact sets attains its extrema, it would follow that $P$ vanishes somewhere on the disc; contradiction.

The condition for Liouville's theorem isn't "bounded by infinity" whatever that is. It's bounded by something not infinity.
